# Stream Video in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, opencv, video, udp

I have two machines that encode/decode packets as follows: they are read and encoded on the first machine, sent to the second machine, then decoded there. This is to prevent loss.

I would like to demo the code by testing it with video: ideally, video is recorded live with webcam, dynamically encoded/decoded, then decoded results are played on a separate screen.

The closest resource I can find is [this link](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~teammco/misc/udp_video/), which is both outdated and seemingly incomplete.

In particular, when I read in a frame from OpenCV, I assume I'll have to divide it into little chunks so that I can encode them, send them over a UDP socket, then decode them. In addition, on the client side, I should be able to take this decoded data and output it back as a video stream. However, I am not sure of 1) the best way to divide the data into packets and 2) how to reconstruct frames from received packets. If you could point me to any relevant resources, that would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use something like RTSP.

Comment: This is more for the purpose of demonstrating loss mitigation, I would ideally like to keep the data transfer the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like you're encoding/decoding packets? How are you "encoding" them? Are you referring to network coding?

The act of encoding e.g using the H.264 codec compresses the packets making it considerably easier to send them over the network. Even if you're wanting to come up with some network-coding based error recovery, you should perform the operations on compressed video data.

Secondly, the Real-Time Transport Protocol (RTP or [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550)) and codec-specific payload formats (e.g. [RFC6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184)) have been specified to address 1) how to split a compressed video frame into multiple RTP packets (if necessary i.e. compressed packet size > MTU), and 2) how to reconstruct them at the receiver.

They also solve a number of other problems such as packet-reordering, media synchronisation, reporting/calculating receiver quality such as loss, jitter, RTT, etc.

As @Hobo Sapiens pointed out, why reinvent the wheel, when people out there have spent a lot of time coming up with tested solutions. In this case I think RTSP is a bit overkill though. (It provides signaling for session setup and control)

You can hard-code the ports, setup a RTP/UDP receiver on the one machine, and an RTP sender on the other.

Also, there are great open source libraries that have implemented RTP/RTCP RTSP such as [live555](http://www.live555.com) that you may want to take a look at before rolling out your own. It takes a lot of time and effort implementing the standards correctly.

**EDIT**
I suspect going the standards route may be too much effort, alternatively you can take the usable parts such as sequence numbers from the RTP specification (allowing you to reorder the packets and detect losses), and NAL unit fragmentation from the RFC6184 specification and construct your own custom header giving you the minimal functionality required.

Comment: By Encoding/Decoding, I'm referring to a Forward Error Correction Scheme. The Encoder reads in packets and constructs some redundant/repair packets. Then, the packets are sent from the Encoder to the Decoder with some loss induced. Then, I want to see how much the Decoder can reconstruct with the source packets and repair packets it has received.

Comment: Ok, figured as much, in that case adapt the sequence number and fragmentation schemes from the standards for your purposes and then apply FEC to video-encoded (e.g H264) packets. You definitely don't want to protect uncompressed media as your data rates will be huge likely inducing even more loss.